# how to fetch data from past week in sql

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

Currently My query is fetching data from current date to past 7 days .I want to fetch data from past week .Means If today is 2013-06-20 then data should be fetched from last week(2013-06-10 to 2013-06-16).I Searched many forum for exact answer but am still unable to find.

Here is my query

```
 SELECT CONVERT(varchar(25),PostDate,107) AS duration, count(*) AS posts
    FROM MDBDetails WHERE 
      DateAdd(dd, 0, DateDiff(dd, 0, PostDate)) <= DateAdd(dd, 0, DateDiff(dd, 0, GETDATE())) AND 
      DateAdd(dd, 0, DateDiff(dd, 0, PostDate)) >= DateAdd(dd, 0, DateDiff(dd, 0, GETDATE())) - 7

          GROUP BY  CONVERT(varchar(25),PostDate,107)
          ORDER BY duration
```

Comment: you need to tell us which DB this is. there's no real standard date/time functions in sql, so every DB implements their own.

Comment: Is it means you need to fetch data before 7 days.

Comment: @MarcB: actually there is a standard on date time handling. Using the `interval` datatype, e.g.: `where postdate <= current_date - interval '7' day` would be ANSI SQL and is actually understood by a wide range of DBMS.

Comment: I am Using sql Server 2008.

Comment: @JDeveloper I want to fetch data from last week starting from Monday(2013-06-10 ) to Sunday(2013-06-16)date

Answer (score 3, accepted):

USE **DATEDIFF(week, , )**

```
 SELECT CONVERT(varchar(25),PostDate,107) AS duration, count(*) AS posts
 FROM MDBDetails 
 WHERE DATEDIFF(week, PostDate,GETDATE()) = 1
 GROUP BY  CONVERT(varchar(25),PostDate,107)
 ORDER BY duration
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code should return the monday of the previous week.

```
SELECT DATEADD(WEEK, -1, DATEADD(WEEK, DATEDIFF(WEEK, 0, SYSDATETIME()), 0));
```

Comment: Indeed this is returning last monday.How to fetch data for last Monday to Sunday. Please tell in details.Am not good in sql Queries

Comment: Just add 6 days to the date that gets returned by the above query, but I think the other answers might be better. Try out the answer provided by jpw.

Answer (score 1):

The datepart function can get you the week number. Subtract 1 and you have the previous week.

```
SELECT DATEPART(WEEK,GETDATE()) -1
```

Then you can filter your data using week number and year for instance.

Comment: This is language dependent.  If you have a login with language set to Spanish, you may get different results depending on the day you run the query.  You should include "Set DATEFIRST 7" before running this code just to make sure you get consistent results regardless of the login.