# Getting specific date values in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I need to perform a query in which a require date value to be `current date(or specific date) - 7 days`. I came across many solutions like these,

`(SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEADD(DD, DATEDIFF(DD, 0, GETDATE()), -7),120))`

However, for getting a week's value, i found a similar solution from [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17199287/how-to-fetch-data-from-past-week-in-sql)

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(25),PostDate,107) AS duration, count(*) AS posts
 FROM MDBDetails 
 WHERE DATEDIFF(week, PostDate,GETDATE()) = 1
 GROUP BY  CONVERT(varchar(25),PostDate,107)
 ORDER BY duration
```

But, a simple query like `GETDATE() -7` or the below code seems to do the required job for me.

```
DECLARE @Date DATETIME = '12/25/13'
SELECT @Date-7
```

My question is that, isn't the above method of **subtracting** date with a numerical value a good practice? 
Of course I get the use of `DATEDIFF` can be extended to specify months and years too. But, is the above method a good practice? Is it necessary to use only `DATEDIFF` method to get the exact date values? Are there any major drawbacks or differences when compared to the first two methods? (except for subtracting months and years).

Comment: The question is unclear. The condition `WHERE DATEDIFF(week, PostDate,GETDATE()) = 1` doeesn't give values like `some date - 7 days ago`. Take a look at this demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5bd99/14 This demo shows, that the condition select dates between 4 and 10 days ago, not only 7 days ago. Either this condition is wrong or your question is misleading.

Comment: My problem addresses both the cases of getting value by week and by date. That is why I posted all three cases to get the date values. My question targets the difference between them and coding practises rather than the actual methods @kordirko.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd better use `DATEADD` function.

Because if one day you decide to change date type of your column from `DATETIME` or `SMALLDATETIME` to `DATE` there will be an error.

You cannot subtract days from `DATE`. You should only use `DATEADD` function instead.

Comment: Then can you please explain why am I getting correct results for the last query in the question? The project is for an enterprise, so changing the table column format is highly impossible after release.